# Gstreamer critical on Opencv3.0 with VideoCapture

Tags: c++11, ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer, opencv3.0, webcam-capture

I'm working on stereovision and i had to calibrate a dual webcam setup. And for this I have to take some picture from webcam but i cannot reach or open the cameras. I am on OpenCV 3.0, ubuntu 16 AND I'm programming in C++.
I'm using VideoCapture cap(0) to get an image from camera. If i check if it succeded with a if(!cap.isopened), i show that something wrong with the openning of the camera and i get this errror on my terminal

(process:11366): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

I'm sorry for my bad english 
Thank you for your future response

Comment: Flagged as possible duplicate, please can you review the other questions and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue (Arch Linux), any hints so far?